# What can we say about $\ker(\theta)$ and $\mathrm{im}(\theta)$ of $\theta: S_3 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{15}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

θ : S3 → Z15 is a group homomorphism.

I know the kerθ={x∈S3: θ(x)=$[0]$}.  Obviously we can say θ(e)=$[0]$, however I believe there is more to say about the kernel...

Meanwhile the Imθ is a subset of Z15.  I also know |Imθ| is divisble by 15 and the |Imθ| is divisble by gcd(6,15)=3.  So the |Imθ|=1 or |Imθ|=3.

S3/Kerθ is isomporhic to Imθ so |S3/Kerθ|=|Imθ| divided by |S3|=6.  Am I on the right track?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Yes. Clearly there is a homomorphism with $|\mathrm{Im}\theta|=1$ (the trivial homomorphism). And you can conclude from what you've already done that $|\mathrm{ker}\theta| = 2$ or $6$. That should give you enough to proceed.

Comment: You're confusing "divides" with "is divisble by".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track but there is much more to say.

$S_3$ is not abelian but $\Bbb Z_{15}$ is abelian so $\theta$ cannot be an isomorphism into its image.  Thus, $\vert \ker(\theta) \vert \gt 1$.

Since $\ker (\theta) \lhd S_3$, we also know $\ker(\theta)  =A_3$ or $\ker(\theta)= S_3$.  But if $\ker(\theta) = A_3$, then $\vert \theta(S_3) \vert = 2$, which isn't possible because $2$ does not divide $\vert \Bbb Z_{15} \vert = 15$.  Thus, $\theta$ must be the trivial homomorphism.

Comment: That actually makes so much sense thanks for that explanation!  Can I say anything else about the Imθ or is what I said you think sufficent.  Also what about the statement I  stated "|S3/Kerθ|=|Imθ| divided by |S3|=6"

Comment: This result says $\operatorname{Im}(\theta)=\{0\}$.  Yes, in general the size of the image of a finite group under any homomorphism must divide the order of the group.